# How do I connect two sets of XY scatter values in MatPlotLib?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am using MatLibPlot to fetch data from an excel file and to create a scatter plot.

Here is a minimal sample table

[image]

In my scatter plot, I have two sets of XY values. In both sets, my X values are country population. I have Renewable Energy Consumed as my Y value in one set and Non-Renewable Energy Consumed in the other set.

For each Country, I would like to have a line from the renewable point to the non-renewable point.

My example code is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

excel_file = 'example_graphs.xlsx'

datasheet = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=0, index_col=0)

ax = datasheet.plot.scatter("Xcol","Y1col",c="b",label="set_one")
datasheet.scatter("Xcol","Y2col",c="r",label="set_two", ax=ax)
ax.show()
```

And it produces the following plot

[image]

I would love to be able to draw a line between the two sets of points, preferably a line I can change the thickness and color of.

Comment: A line between point `(x1,y1)` to `(x2,y2)` is created via `ax.plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2])` in matplotlib.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest If you added a way to do that on sets of data fetched as above, that would make a great answer but either way, thank you!

Comment: If you provided a [mcve] with at least an attempt to solve the problem, I could sure do that.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've edited the question and I hope it has fulfilled the criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, you could simply loop over the dataframe and plot a line for each row.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datasheet = pd.DataFrame({"Xcol" : [1,2,3],
                          "Y1col" : [25,50,75],
                          "Y2col" : [75,50,25]})

ax = datasheet.plot.scatter("Xcol","Y1col",c="b",label="set_one")
datasheet.plot.scatter("Xcol","Y2col",c="r",label="set_two", ax=ax)
for n,row in datasheet.iterrows():
    ax.plot([row["Xcol"]]*2,row[["Y1col", "Y2col"]], color="limegreen", lw=3, zorder=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]